# angularjs translate works only in html ?

Tags: angularjs, function, angular-translate

i have used angular-translate, and it works great.
But now the problem is how can i use it in my controller functions?

normal we can use it in the html templates as `{{ 'mystring' | translate }}`

but i actualy want to do this:

```
function bla(){
  var myvalue = 'mystring' | tranlate
 return value;
}
```

and then in my html `{{ value }}`

Comment: 'translate' is a filter inside angular-translate it can work in that way. Why do you need that?

Comment: i found this... but it doesn't work 
http://plnkr.co/edit/RpRcP3?p=preview

Comment: i need it for the page title in the routes
`code $routeProvider.when('/projects', {
            templateUrl:  templateUrl+'/page/projects/index.html',
            controller: 'projectController'            
            },
            pageTitle:  $translate('users'),
            authenticated: true
        });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Docs,to use filter inside controller is as follows.

> $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)

You need to write something below

```
app.controller('MainCtr', ['$scope','$translate','$filter', function ($scope,$translate,$filter) {

         $translate.use($scope.language.langCode);

         $scope.data = $filter('translate')('Title');//where Title is language dependant 

   });]);
```

[Demo to call filter inside controller](https://plnkr.co/edit/ljEbFh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to show dinamic content on your html. To achieve this you should think in other way to do it using angular-translate. I can guess you are trying to achieve this:

**controller.js**

```
$scope.mystring = 'MY_LITERAL_CODE';
```

**inde.html**

```
<span>{{ mystring | translate }}</span>
```